# Line number of matlab does not show

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab 2016a version.
I go the preference--->Editor/Debugger--->Display--->General display options--->Show line numbers, checked. Then I reboot the matlab, however, in the text editor, there is still no line numbers.

Does anyone encounter same problem before?

Comment: What operating system? Do you have a screenshot showing the issue?

Comment: This is probably the many year old bug that Mathworks doesn't seem to care much about https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/299887. Toggling between screen split seems to work for some people.

Comment: you do not need to reboot matlab, just click apply